# The reading of a song: what a beginner in composition needs to pay attention when reading a song?

Tags: scales, composition, key, melody, songwriting

Firstly, I'm a beginner in composition and all of my songs were quite "intuitive". I'm at a stage where I really need to know music theory in order to produce better songs.

---

### I) Introduction

Now, I would like some tips and tricks when reading a song in order to understand its "structure". I would like to explain my point looking at a concrete example:

> Consider the melody by Hans Zimmer "Herald of the Change". You can listen it at [1] and [2].
>
> 1. D1 A1 C#1 D2 A1 C#1 D2 A2
> 2. D1 A#1 A1 Gb A1 A#1 C#1 D2
> 3. D#1 G1 D2 D#2 G1 A#1 F#2 G2
> 4. Eb1 G1 A#1 A A#1 D#2 G2 A2
>
> This melody is a whole sequence, of course. But I've just separated it into four phrases.

Well, the heuristic question is: "what is happening here?" or "why this song was composed the way it was?"; the answer for these questions can change. For instance, if we ask in terms of what feelings and atmosphere this song wants to transmit, you'll probably need to read and know the "Dune" narrative and then compose a song that suits its plot; this is something beyond the plain music theory. But, I would like to ask in a technical sense of composing.

### II) My Question

**My question is: what is happening in that melody in terms of scales, key progression and song writing theory?** Please, this is a very broad question, but as I said, I would like some tips and tricks because I would like to compose something similar. In order to do that I need to "reverse engineer" the song.

---

[1]

[2]

Comment: I think that "Gb" in 2. is really an "F#".

Answer (score 1):

Asking for analysis is off topic, but "some tips and tricks" go in the direction of general analysis strategy include:

- Try to "reduce" the arpeggiation and melodic elements to a basic outline of chords (or important bass tones) and scales.
- Look for musical sections and any aspects on repetition and variation that might occur for a section.
- Look at the thematic character of sections on whether there is contrast or similarity between sections. Thematic character is where you might determine things like whether the music is "tune" oriented, like jazz standards and traditional songs, or more riff/groove/rhythm oriented like some rock songs or some modern orchestral music.
- Note the tonalities used between sections. Often changes in tonality (key change, change of tonic, change of mode) are used to delineate sections. Be aware sometimes tonality doesn't change between sections, but that is still an important aspect of musical structure, in other words all sections in the same key is a template for tonal organization, just like `tonic dominant relative-minor tonic subdominant tonic` is a common "classical" template.

Song really means something sung, but this example you posted is a movie soundtrack. There can be difference between the two. In an actual song you might look at the lyrics and what musical devices are used to express the meaning of the lyrics. You don't have that aspect in this soundtrack. What you might look for in the soundtrack instead are orchestral devices, building up and reducing the layers of instruments and using orchestral crescendos. This soundtrack is much more about "painting" a mood and using musical devices to sustain the mood without monotony rather than writing a nice memorable melody.

In the piano version some of that orchestral stuff becomes choices like chord voicing (many/few voices, voices meaning notes in the chords), register contrasting low and high ranges of the keyboard, and crescendo. In this "song" the dynamics, crescendo, seems to me a critical and specific aspect of the music. In that piano version you better play the dynamic changes correctly to get the right effect. Compare that to a standard type song - for example the song *Summertime* by Gershwin - where performer/arranger has a lot of latitude about how to handle dynamics, because most of the song is about melody and chords.